# Is the function identically zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x, y)$ be a continuous, real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Suppose that, for every rectangular region $R$ of area 1, the double integral of $f(x, y)$
over $R$ equals 0. Must $f(x, y)$ be identically 0?

Comment: What did you try? How did you put to use the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: My working hypothesis is that is not true. I am trying to construct an example.

Comment: Can you think of any counterexamples?

Comment: If your tries at showing this is not true fail, I suggest trying to prove it is true. And to do that, a hint is: small rectangles around a point.

Comment: @ZettaSuro Can you?

Comment: @Did: Rectangles in the question are  of area 1. This implies that these cannot be small, is not so?

Comment: This was Problem A6 from the 2012 Putnam Competition. The solutions have been published, and the AoPS wiki also has solutions by those who attempted the exam, so there is no need for this question to be on MSE.

Comment: Oops... then one must be more careful. Sorry about the noise.

Comment: @proximal: Thank you. I had in mind the following modification: $f$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $g(y)=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx$.
Since the intgeral of $f$ over $[0,1]\times[y,y+1]$ equals that over $[0,1]\times[y+\epsilon,y+1+\epsilon]$, we conclude $\int_y^{y+\epsilon} g(y)dy=\int_{y+1}^{y+1+\epsilon}g(y) dy$ and in the limit $g(y+1)=g(y)$, that is $g$ is periodic with period $1$.

Comment: It solves the question. I thought about the discontinuous function $f(x,y):=1/\text{denominator of}$ $ x $ if $x$ and $y$ are rationals and 0 otherwise.